# How to make Outlook display envelope icon for unread mail in other folders than Inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I get a bunch of SVN commit messages to my email, and I created a rule to move them to a separate folder ("commits"). Now, the problem I have is that when I get a new commit message, Outlook no longer displays the little envelope icon in the tray.

The envelope icon is displayed just fine as long as the new mail is in my Inbox, but it doesn't show up when it's in any other folder.

Is it possible to get the envelope to show in other folders than inbox?

Comment: as far as i know, there is no way to achieve this. MS just made it this way.
I too use GaryJL's method.

Comment: Check out @PetrMpp's method. The app works pretty well. I put it as a catch-all at the top of my rules list. I have some rules that filter out "corporate spam" for which I do not care to be notified. I put those above the notify app rule, and flag them to stop processing additional rules.

Answer (score 10):

It’s pretty old question but any way…perhaps this will help those who do not like pop-up message boxes.
The rule wizard has an action “start application”. I have written a simple app which shows little envelope icon in the tray. When you double click on the icon it brings up Outlook window like original Outlook icon does (and no pop-up message boxes).
The app and source code are uploaded on github, [here](https://github.com/Petrik7/Prototypes/tree/master/SysTryApp).

You can download source code and compile the app by yourself or you can just download executable from bin folder as given [here](https://github.com/Petrik7/Prototypes/blob/master/SysTryApp/bin/Release/SysTryApp.exe).

Point `start application` action to the app and it will show little envelope icon in the tray when rule is triggered.

Perhaps this will help those who do not like pop-up message boxes.

Comment: Great solution!  The only problem is the BringProcessToFront won't work if Outlook is minimized to the toolbar.  Instead you should use Process.Start("OUTLOOK.exe", "/recycle");  This work regardless of whether it's currently in the taskbar or minimized to the toolbar.

Comment: +1 for creating your own solution. It would be even better if it went away by itself when I read the new mail, like the Outlook one does.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem. Instead, I settled for displaying a 'New Mail Item' Dialog, or displaying a desktop notification. At least this way there is some notification of a new message.

The dialog and notification can be added to the rule which filters the messages into a different folder. I use the Dialog for all urgent mail (customer contact).

Comment: Is there an option for this on OSX? Doesn't appear to be any sort of "display Desktop Notification" action for rules...

Comment: @JakeWilson Just select the Client Rules section and then you have "Desktop Notification".