# Outlook 2010 alert when incoming mail is moved to a folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Outlook display envelope icon for unread mail in other folders than Inbox?](https://superuser.com/questions/17541/how-to-make-outlook-display-envelope-icon-for-unread-mail-in-other-folders-than)

I have a few rules applied for my incoming mail (i.e. When I get mail from my co-workers they are all redirected to a certain folder).

When this redirection happens I don't get an alert or notification. How can I change this? I would like to see at least the small envelope next to the Outlook icon on my taskbar.

Comment: This works ... http://superuser.com/questions/73052/how-to-enable-email-desktop-alerts-for-inbox-folders-in-outlook-2007?newreg=7582a29f6ff746209e43efe53004dbc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some email rules are applied server-side... others are client-side.  I think you're running into a server-side rule (yes, its configured inside outlook... but the rule is stored in the exchange server) that moves the email into the folder before your client ever sees it.  If it doesn't land in the inbox... you'll never get a notification.