# Outlook 2010; filtering and desktop notifications

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Outlook display envelope icon for unread mail in other folders than Inbox?](https://superuser.com/questions/17541/how-to-make-outlook-display-envelope-icon-for-unread-mail-in-other-folders-than)

I get notifications on my desktop when receiving email. I just created two folders within the inbox folder and set filtering rules for what incoming mail should go into those folders.

Problem is I'm not getting desktop notifications for the incoming mail filtered into those folders.

My guess is that notifications are associated with the inbox folder rather than mail receipt per se, which would explain why it doesn't notify about stuff that hits the spam filter.

How do I configure notifications to associate with folders other than and in addition to the inbox folder?